# Python - Regex - jump a incorrect line

Tags: python, regex

I try parse logs in python. I use regular expression operations. It works fine if logs are in standard format. Standard format look like this :

```
[158.197.233.55] : - : - :[03/Jan/2018:06:06:21 +0100] : "GET / HTTP/1.1" : 200 : 3041
```

Problem is that some of logs are not in standard format because they were incorrectly written. I have incorrect logs like this :

```
[158.197.238.112 : - : - [16/Jan/2018:17:32:02 +0100] : GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/css/printview.css?v=4.6.6deb4 HTTP/1.1 : 200 : 988
```

or this

```
50.93.204.105 : - : - : [07/Jan/2018:15:53:34 +0100] GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1 404 290`
```

or this

```
 [158.197
.233.55] : - : - [03/Jan/2018:06:16:31 +0100]
```

or many another types of incorrect logs.
Problem is I cant fix logs. And I also cant write regular expression which will parse all types of incorrect logs. I try this but there is too many incorrect types. Any idea how to solve this ? I think it will be best : if regrex find line witch `dont match group` just jump incorrect line. It is possible do this in python ?  Or is there another way ?

Comment: What in the log are you trying to extract?

Comment: I want ip adress, time, query, status and size and ...everything in between " : " is one group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare lines and skip if the line doesn't fit the standard format, you can use:

```
import re 

for input_string in all_strings:
    output = re.match('your_regex', input_string)
    if output:
        do_your_stuff()
```